# JFreeChart large dataset

Tags: java, bar-chart, jfreechart

I'm creating a bar chart for my database. Everything works except one thing: the data from DB is large, so the bars look tiny. I used scroll pane, but that didn't work. Here is my chart creator:

```
JFreeChart barChart = ChartFactory.createBarChart(
    "du "+du+" a "+a,           
    "date",            
    "Score",            
    categoryDataset,          
    PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,           
    true, true, true);
```

Here is my chart panel:

```
chartPanel = new ChartPanel( chart );
chartPanel.setMaximumDrawWidth(1000); 
chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(2000, 1000));
chartPanel.revalidate();
chartPanel.repaint();
chartPanel.setBounds(1, 1, 680, 420);
```

Here is a picture for clarification:

[image: bar chart]

Comment: Try [`SlidingCategoryDataset`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bjfreechart%5d%20SlidingCategoryDataset).

Comment: Since your x-axis is a value scale (dates) I'd recommend that you use a chart with an `XYPlot` rather than a `CategoryPlot` (which means you'll also need to change the class you use to represent your dataset).